# Proving by induction inequalities that lack the variable on the right side: $\frac{1}{n + 1}+\frac{1}{n + 2}+...+\frac{1}{n+(n+1)}\le \frac{5}{6}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality, summation, induction, harmonic-numbers

Doing proof by induction exercises with inequalities, I got stuck on one that is a bit different from the others. There is no $n$ term on the rightmost part of the inequality:

> Prove that the following holds for all $n \ge 1$:
>
> $$\frac{1}{n + 1}+\frac{1}{n + 2}+...+\frac{1}{n+(n+1)}\le \frac{5}{6}$$

All the other proofs I did before had some $n$ involved there, but now there is none. I wonder how will this difference affect my standard attempt:

---

Test for $n = 1$:

$$\frac{1}{3} \le \frac{5}{6} \implies 6 \le 15$$

---

We have to prove that it holds for $n + 1$, that is:

$$\frac{1}{n + 1}+\frac{1}{n + 2}+...+\frac{1}{n+(n+1)}+\frac{1}{(n + 1)+(n+2)}\le \frac{5}{6}$$

---

Asssume
$$\frac{1}{n + 1}+\frac{1}{n + 2}+...+\frac{1}{n+(n+1)}\le \frac{5}{6}$$

---

We start off with

$$\frac{1}{n + 1}+\frac{1}{n + 2}+...+\frac{1}{n+(n+1)}+\frac{1}{(n + 1)+(n+2)}\le \frac{5}{6}$$

And now I see the problem. Normally, I apply the hypothesis first on this part:

$$\color{blue}{\frac{1}{n + 1}+\frac{1}{n + 2}+...+\frac{1}{n+(n+1)}}+\frac{1}{(n + 1)+(n+2)}\le \frac{5}{6}$$

But all it yields is this:

$$\color{blue}{\left ( \textrm{something smaller or equal than } \frac{5}{6} \right )} + \frac{1}{(n + 1)+(n+2)}\le \frac{5}{6}$$

If I move $\frac{1}{(n + 1)+(n+2)}$ to the other side, all I get is

$$\color{blue}{\left ( \textrm{something smaller or equal than } \frac{5}{6} \right )} \le \frac{5}{6} - \frac{1}{(n + 1)+(n+2)}$$

Which cannot be guaranteed.

How can I prove this, then?

Comment: If it is not compulsory to use induction... are you familiar with A.M-H.M inequality?

Comment: The first proof that comes to my mind doesn’t use induction. $$\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n+1}\frac1k<\int_n^{2n+1}\frac{dx}x=\ln(2n+1)-\ln n=\ln\left(2+\frac1n\right)\;,$$ which is less than $\frac56$ for all $n\ge 4$. Then just check the result for $n=1,2,3$.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: Well, it's an induction exercise, so I should use it. I don't recognise that term for inequality (or perhaps I do, but in Spanish) - I will take a look at it, thanks.

Comment: The statement that you're trying to prove in the induction step is not quite correct.  The sum ought to begin with the term $\frac{1}{n+2}$.

Comment: Ok.. I am sure it would be easy with that inequality but i will try with induction also

Comment: @SammyBlack : Oh yes... Just now i could see that there is an error in his argument.. juts after posting my answer...

Comment: @SammyBlack: Someone told me that there is no problem with starting from $\frac{1}{n+1}$, because it just means that the succession begins from $\frac{1}{n+1}$ and ends on $\frac{1}{(n+1)+1}$. Is that right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $$a_n=\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n+1}\frac1k\;,$$ and show that the sequence $\langle a_n:n\ge 1\rangle$ is decreasing. There’s more in the spoiler-protected block below.

> $\displaystyle\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n+1}\frac1k-\sum_{k=n+2}^{2n+3}\frac1k=\frac1{n+1}-\frac1{2n+2}-\frac1{2n+3}=\frac1{2n+2}-\frac1{2n+3}=\ldots$

Answer (score 2):

we assume

$$\frac{1}{n + 1}+\frac{1}{n + 2}+...+\frac{1}{n+(n+1)}\le \frac{5}{6}$$

looking for $n+1$ case, we see :
$$\frac{1}{n + 2}+...+\frac{1}{n+(n+1)}+\frac{1}{(n+1)+(n+2)}=\frac{1}{n + 2}+...+\frac{1}{n+(n+1)}+\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+2}=\frac{1}{n + 1}+\frac{1}{n + 2}+...+\frac{1}{n+(n+1)}-\frac{1}{n+2}\leq \frac{5}{6}-\frac{1}{n+2}\leq \frac{5}{6}$$